# How do I set specific key for keydown event listener?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', randomD(e) {
   if (e.keyCode === 32);   
});


 function randomD(e) {
 const wordList = ['Carvedilol', 'Histrelin', 'Kadcyla', 'Mavyret', 'Paracetamol',     
 'Raloxifene', 'Saxagliptin'];
 const display = document.querySelector("#wordDisplay");
 const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length);
 const ranWord = wordList[random];
 display.innerHTML = ranWord;
 }
```

I want the key to be spacebar. It says after the if argument that "e" is declared but its value is never read.  I'm a beginner and am not sure how to fix this or what the error indicates exactly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are not defining the listener properly. Either reference the already existing function by using just the name - `randomD` - or write the function body inside an anonymous inline function when calling `addEventListener`. You're trying to do both, which is invalid syntax.

Comment: Thank you that set me on the right path I appreciate your help.